# Inconsistent Results When threadpool larger than 1

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, not a native java user:

I have a class that implements callable to calculate vector / plane intersections from a given point. 
When I iterate over a grid I want to dispatch a thread to do each row of the grid.

If I set Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1) it works perfectly. When i set it to 2 i get inconsistent results, - it partially skips some of each row, the intersection list being returned has fewer entries in than expected.

I suspect this is due to some memory clashing but it's my understanding that each thread should have its own set of independent data objects since i submit with new doProjection(). (is there a way to guarantee this / enforce synchronized access if they are passed by ref?

Submission / set up code

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
CompletionService<List<Integer>> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<List<Integer>>(service);
List<Future<List<Integer>>> contentsfutures = new ArrayList<>(subdiv[dim1]);
for (int dir1=0;dir1<subdiv[dim1] ;dir1++) {
    // make this so it selects the shortest side - adjust direction vector and projpoint[i]
    aprojpoint[dim1]=aprojpoint[dim1] + (adelta[dim1]*(dir1+1));      
    Future<List<Integer>> keepthis = ecs.submit(new doProjection(aprojpoint,adelta,aprojvector,asurfacetridef,dim1,dim2,subdiv[dim2],dx,dy,dz,meshsize,bounds,centroidmap,dir1));
    contentsfutures.add(keepthis);
}
List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (int dir1=0;dir1<subdiv[dim1] ;dir1++) {
    try {
        Future<List<Integer>> res1 = ecs.take();
        temp = res1.get();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    if (!temp.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i=0;i<temp.size()-2;i++) {
            // do stuff in my model
        }
    }
}
```

callable class:

```
public class doProjection implements Callable<List<Integer>>{
     final private float[]projpoint;
     final private float[]initalpoint;
     final private float[]delta;
     final private float[] projvector;
     final private int dim1;
     final private int dim2;
     final private int ndim2; 
     final private int dir1;
     final private Map<Integer,tridef> surfacetridef; // big map
     final private float meshsize;
     final private float dx, dy, dz;
     final private gridbox bounds; // essentially float[][]
     //all of the items in the constructor ideally would be readonly
     final private Map<String,Integer> centroidmap; // big map

     public doProjection(float[] projpoint2, float[] delta2, float[] projvector2, 
                         Map<Integer,tridef> surfacetridef2,int dim11,int dim12, 
                         int dim12n,float dx2, float dy2, float dz2, float meshsize2, 
                         gridbox bounds2, Map<String,Integer> centroidmap2, int dir12) {
         this.dim1= dim11;
         this.dim2=dim12;
         this.projvector = projvector2;
         this.delta = new float[3];
         // etc other vars declared the same as the args
     }

     public List<Integer> call() throws Exception {
         List<Integer> keeplist = new ArrayList<>();
         int dir111 = dir1;
         for (int dir2=0;dir2<ndim2 ;dir2++) {           
             List<Float> intersectionlist=new ArrayList<>();
             // get list of distances to intersections with surface of interest.       
             intersectionlist = projectpointtoshells(surfacetridef,projpoint,projvector);
             // sorted list
             if (!intersectionlist.isEmpty()) {
                 List<Integer> subkeeplist = addelmstokeeplist( bounds, origin, endpoint,  dx, dy, dz, meshsize,centroidmap);
                 keeplist.addAll(subkeeplist);
             }
         }
     }

     keeplist.add(dir111); //some debug additions
     keeplist.add(ndim2);
     return keeplist;
}
```

Thank you!

Visualisation: - missing gaps / spurious results inside the blue line should be solid

[image]

Comment: Could you please reduce your code to the necessary minimum to show the inconsistent behavior? Right now it is hard to see the control flow with all those fields, parameters and math. I'd guess those do not have an impact on the thread behavior. And if they do, we might be one step closer to the solution already.

Comment: I've removed a lot of the maths, Half the problem is im not sure where the inconsistent behavious gets introduced, as it works perfectly on a single thread.

Comment: @LHolness, do you mutate the contents of `doProjection.projvector` anywhere?

Comment: Not projvector, projpoint gets stepped along the grid but the vector is constant

Comment: If you need to mutate the references you are passing (arrays, `Map`s, etc.) you need to make copies in the `doProjection` constructor. The alternative is that you add explicit synchronization around the shared state so that you are not reading/writing to it from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, that was the hint I needed, creating a copy of the projpoint in the constructor fixed it, reduces my processing time by a factor of 4!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sean Bright provided the insight,

I had failed to realise that the changing variable projpoint was shared across threads and so was being inconsistently updated by multiple threads.

Declaring a new float[3] in the doProjector constructor and then assigning the values from projpoint resolves this by ensuring each call has its own local copy of the projection point, all the other variables are readonly so are generally happy.